# Apache Tomcat cannot start with 2 webapps on Windows 10

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, tomcat7, java-7

I experience a strange error during moving my environment from Windows XP (32 bit) to Windows 10 (64 bit) machine.

My Apache Tomcat service runs properly with 2 webapps on old server. When I moved my apps to new server (windows 10) I can not start tomcat with 2 webapps simultaneously. I can still start tomcat with one webapp - regardless which app out of 2 is put in webapps directory.

My catalina logs ends with:

> INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache
>   Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\swanny sie 18, 2017 9:08:17 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute INFO: At least one JAR
>   was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for
>   this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs
>   were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve
>   startup time and JSP compilation time.

without finally stating that the server has been started like that:

> Server startup in XXXXX ms

My old machine used -Xmx1024m. I increased the memory of new machine to -Xmx2048m to be sure that these are not memory problems (and it's 64 bits after all). The problem however still exists.

Could anyone point me some direction?
Regards

Comment: I have discovered that when I have 2 webapps my logs says: "[localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@e4faa3f: defining beans" so it seems that spring does not get up properly. What's interesting - I have no such an entry when I start only one webapp.

Answer (score 0):

Use 64 bit tomcat and check it.

Comment: I used 32-bit/64-bit Windows Service Installer. I suppose it installed Tmcat correctly.